# `ModuleNotFoundError` when running script from `console_scripts` but not when importing via Python console

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying to set up a proper Python package for distribution and I'm running into problems with the `console_scripts` property of my `setup.py` file. I have the following in my setup:

```
<...>
entry_points={"console_scripts": ["solve_cipher=cipher_solver.solve_cipher:main"]}
<...>
```

I have packaged and sent to the test PyPI and then installed my packaged in a new virtual environment. Now, the command `solve_cipher` is available but running it gives me:

```
$ solve_cipher 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markus/.virtualenvs/cipher_solver_debug_pypi/bin/solve_cipher", line 6, in <module>
    from cipher_solver.solve_cipher import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cipher_solver'
```

However, if I just start Python and run the same import line, it works just fine:

```
$ python
>>> from cipher_solver.solve_cipher import main
>>>
```

Why does this happen? My project layout is as follows:

```
cipher_solver
    <...>
    cipher_solver
        consts.py
        simple.py
        solve_cipher.py
        utils.py
    <...>
    setup.py
```

Comment: `which python`? `head -1 /Users/markus/.virtualenvs/cipher_solver_debug_pypi/bin/solve_cipher`?

Comment: @phd #!/Users/markus/.virtualenvs/cipher_solver_debug_pypi/bin/python3.7

Comment: Looks good. Is it the same as `which python`? When you `import cipher_solver` from the command line what is the current directory? The one where `setup.py` resides?

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue, see answer below.

Comment: @phd Hmm, I think I spoke too soon about the answer. Yes, they are the same Python binary, and I run it from where `setup.py` is. Any other ideas?

Comment: When you are in the directory where `setup.py` resides Python does import from the local subdirectory. `cd` to a different directory and try import from the command line again — does it work?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I made no significant changes, but right now it's the other way around. Running the console script works, but importing gives an error. I've changed directory to some unrelated place and installed my package from the test pypi in a new virtualenv. Running `solve_cipher` works fine. But running `python` and then `from cipher_solver.solve_cipher import main` gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cipher_solver.solve_cipher'`

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I used `setuptools.find_packages()` in my `setup.py` and it turns out that method needs `__init__.py` files in packages and subpackages for them to be found. I thought this was no longer necessary in Python 3.3+ but apparently in some cases.

Comment: You might want to give [`find_namespace_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages) a try. Dependeing on your exact requirements tt might be helpful.

Comment: @sinoroc I don't have any namespace packages.

Comment: as far as I know, it shouldn't matter if you have namespace packages or not. Maybe the name of the function is a bit misleading, not sure exactly. Anyway, last time I tried this function was able to collect packages that do not contain any `__init__.py` package initializer. But to be honest, I still prefer putting `__init__.py` in all my packages and use the normal `find_packages` function. I just thought I would mention this alternative.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it. I'm fine with the `__init__.py` files, as long as I can get it to work :)